# Simple Python server setup

Tags: python, http

I am trying to learn python (coming from PHP), and want to set up the simplest web server so I can start coding.

I found the integrated HTTP server, so I figured it should be the easiest way.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/py# python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

The webserver is working, accessing `http://test.dev:8000/test.py` (thanks `/etc/hosts`) works - but shows me the contents of the file ( `print('Hello world!');` ), without interpreting it.

How to properly set up the server / interpretor ?

Comment: Does test.py have executable ("+x") permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is for writing programs in general, not only web-sites.

`SimpleHTTPServer` is really just a trivial HTTP server, it serves files. It doesn't try to interpret code.

If you want to do web-development with Python, you should be using a *web framework*. [`web.py`](http://webpy.org/) is a good choice, you can check its [tutorial](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial). Another option is [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), which also has a brilliant [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).

Both of them have simple development servers built in, so you'll be able to start experimenting easily.

Comment: Gave it a try with Django, and it's working perfectly (the tutorial is brilliant :P)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting out with python I would recommend you start with scripts that can be run from the console using python interpreter. (*eg: python run1.py*)

Once you have mastered the basics, you can move onto web programming. (I am guessing that you want to try web programming since you mention a web server.) In this case, you have multiple options (all of which work with Apache):

- Django framework : Really good framework, has a built-in webserver and has fantastic documentation (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html).
  You need to know python basics first
- WSGI: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/ : Apache module for running python code