# Get data from python with ajax

Tags: python, ajax, simplehttpserver

I'm passing data to a python script with ajax but I can't get that data back. The most I managed to get is 'undefined' or the script text itself (no idea why...). Currently, after a lot of tries, I get nothing.

I don't know if this is related but I'm new to python and didn't want to use any framework, so I'm using SimpleHTTPServer. Anyway...

This is the ajax call

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "con-test.py",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (responseText) {
            alert(responseText); /* responseText.stuff is not working either */
        }
    });
});
```

And the script con-test.py

```
import json

result = {}
result['stuff'] = 'banana'
json_string = json.dumps(result)

print result # also tried return result
```

Comment: There is a sample of SimpleHTTPServer sending an ajax response in in the [simplehttpserver tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/simplehttpserver/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SimpleHTTPServer` for web-apps. It is not executing any code, it simply serves raw files (that's why you only managed to get the script text). I suggest using some web-framework; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998983/simple-python-server-setup/).

Comment: Oh... I see. Well can you suggest a simple framework? I tried django and it's nice but I'm looking for something less restricting (I may not want to use MVC).

Comment: @YoniLevy Django is not restricting at all. It is a set of nice modules (templating, ORM, l10n, URL dispatcher, etc.) and you are free to use only the ones you find useful for your project. I can't really suggest anything as I'm using Django, but hm… well, probably you should look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: [web2py Web Framework](http://www.web2py.com) is also lightweight. A complete list is available [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)