# Execute python script in localhost

Tags: python, apache

I have downloaded and installed python on my PC. I am learning python at this moment so I am a beginner.

Is there anyway I could execute python scripts in localhost (Apache)  and view them in a web browser as  we do with PHP? I am executing the python scripts from CLI at this moment.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Comment: I believe you need to install [`mod_python`](http://www.modpython.org/), too.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998983/simple-python-server-setup/16999365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are multiple solutions, I would take a look at [`mod_python`](http://modpython.org/). Unfortunately, in my experience it is not the easiest thing in the world to set up and requires making changes to httpd.conf, but [this tutorial](http://webpython.codepoint.net/mod_python_tutorial) is helpful (and gives some examples).

Answer (score 0):

[Google App Engine SDK for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) includes a local web server application that simulates the App Engine environment.  It allows for instant server script changes by just saving the file and refreshing the browser.

[The development tutorial is here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/devenvironment)

Once you have your web site working locally, it is easy to deploy it live on Google's App Engine servers.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about Google Apps

Comment: OP didn't ask about mod_python either.  What part of my answer does not give him the ability to execute a python script in localhost?  Do you think someone new to Python will be able to use mod_python?  I know from my own experience that GAE's dev tool is easy to install and use.